# Detect unique users with simultaneous visits

Tags: asp.net, .net, google-analytics

Imagine a simple html page with 3 iframes pointing to the same url:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="http://www.mydom.com/mypage.aspx"></iframe>
    <iframe src="http://www.mydom.com/mypage.aspx"></iframe>
    <iframe src="http://www.mydom.com/mypage.aspx"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

My goal is to track unique visitors in mypage.aspx code behind. Sounds simple but the following:

```
if (Request.Cookies["myc"] == null)
{
    // New visitor!
    Response.Cookies["myc"].Value = myval;
    Response.Cookies["myc"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(10);
}
else
{
    // Returning visitor
}
```

has a problem. Visiting the html page with the 3 iframes I get three simultaneous hits to mypage.aspx and Request.Cookies["myc"] is null all three times while I should understand that it is the same user (1st hit: new visitor, 2nd and 3rd hits: returning visitor for a total of one visitor/user). Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Surely using their IP address would solve this?

Comment: Google Analytics javascript manages to do this, I do not know how but if I insert GA in mypage.aspx I see new and returning visitors correctly. Maybe someone is able to look into GA js (quite complicated and minified).

Comment: GA uses tracking cookies (hence all the fun around the EU cookie directive), so will place a cookie on your machine on first visit, and use that to track you through the site. The problem above would happen with GA as the tracking code would be in the page 3 times - Something that shouldn't happen! I think he should look to move the cookie to the parent page like you would with GA

Comment: Is http://www.mydom.com/mypage.aspx located on a different domain than the simple page? If so, you won't be able to read the cookie values.

Comment: "myc" cookies have mydom.com as domain, so no probs, I can read them. I'm not trying to read cookies from a different domain (the one where the simple page is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is to put the same code in a [webMethod] instead of in PageLoad then call the [WebMethod] from client via js (XMLHttpRequest), you will receive the three calls in sequence. No more probs due to simultaneous hits.

Comment: This is a good solution.  The other option for you if web services is a pain is to have a page before the one you are calling.  With a single page you can then redirect the user and the cookies that have been set should then be available.  Both methods will work.

Answer (score 4):

A very intriguing question!

The core problem is that the internet is an asynchronous, anonymous place.

The browser may submit one of these requests at a time, or all three at the same time, so there is no way to control the order of events on the user's machine.

In addition, the browser does not make any special effort to uniquely identify the user. Any identification system must be jerry-rigged into the request/response cycle. GA uses cookies to tag users and can pull that information with each and every request. Essentially, GA tags the user before they visit your site, thus allowing that service to identify the user on the "first" hit.

Your problem is that you want to implement your own identification solution. You need to somehow include the user's identity in the request. But, until they visit the site, you have no way of doing that. And, given that each simultaneous request will have a different identity embedded in the response, you cannot guarantee that a user will be tagged with a single identity.

Basically, to the best of my knowledge, there is no solution which will allow an anonymous user to be automatically and uniquely identified by your site.

You may be tempted to use IP addresses and that can work in some situations, but it's a very bad solution. Right now I am behind my employers firewall. If you were to use the IP address currently visible to you to identify me, you would see me and the 5,000 other people who work here as a single user. That's a very dangerous system to rely on.

If you really, really need a single identity for each user - one that cannot be circumvented or accidentally trodden on via multiple simultaneous requests, etc - then your only solution is to require the user to explicitly identify themselves on their first request via a value embedded in the POST or GET query or a cookie created during a previous visit.

In your scenario, all three responses could generate a cookie with a unique ID (three ids in succession, each overwriting the previous value). The landing page could be a generic "welcome to my site" page, or something like that. The user could then click a link to visit the site, at which point the last generated cookie (with the last generated id) would be embedded in the request. While you cannot guarantee that only one ID will be generated per user, you can at least be fairly confident that they will be identified by a single ID after the initial round of requests (and before they visit the main content portion of your site).

Of course, you could use a complicated AJAX solution where the response for unidentified users is essentially a container (without an ID). The AJAX could then set a flag within a cookie indicating that it is retrieving an ID, then it could submit the first request. Subsequent AJAX containers would see this cookie and then enter a polling state, waiting for the flag to be cleared. When the first response comes back, the first AJAX container could set the ID in the cookie and change the flag. Then, the remaining containers will detect the flag change and can retrieve the ID from the cookie (rather than sending their own requests).

Once the AJAX container has an ID, it could send a request for content along with the unique ID. Your site could then respond, filling the container with the appropriate data (or simply redirecting to the appropriate page).

This solution, if properly implemented, would more or less guarantee that a user is assigned only one ID. But really, is it worth it? Remember, the cookie and the request "belong" to the user. The user can pretty easily edit both. While there are techniques for detecting an edited identity (most involving some form of encryption), you cannot prevent a user from "anonymizing" themselves if they so choose. Sometimes a halfway solution is sufficient.

Comment: Cyborgx37, thanks for your thoughts. I agree with all your say, as far as I know what I'm trying to achive is not possible but GA does it! If you try to include GA js in mypage.aspx you will see (in GA realtime view) that at a first visit (all cookies removed) you get one new user and two returning users. The point is: how google can do this?

Comment: @Pietro - They may be doing something similar to what I suggested in the second part of my answer: using AJAX. I don't know exactly how they do it, but I'm sure the javascript is accessible if you really want to comb through it. The question is, is it worth it to you?

Comment: (I'd also add that if this was simple to do, Google wouldn't have wasted it's time building an Analytics tool when people could just roll up their own.)

Answer (score 0):

That makes good sense. The request for all of these does not have any cookies the first time, so it will be null in all cases. Remember it should do this as async as possible, it's necessarily linear (it might be, I am not expert at how the flow is).

Instead, look at the Ip address and timestamp. If it is the same, you can work as if it is the same user.

Yes, that solution is not perfect, but it's better than the cookie solution.

Comment: Maybe IP is the solution but where should I store it? Cookie would have the same prob, DB shouldn't be different... How can I let the other (simoultaneous) process/threads know the 'first' IP detected?

Comment: if you call a method which is using the lock keyword, it shouldn't be a problem. Then the threads will wait. 
Then storing in the DB / cache would work.

Comment: This sounds good, thanks :) Could I continue to use cookie instead of DB/Cache and just lock the method? Or cookie are particularly slow?

Comment: Remember when the user requests your iframe, they send a request. This request will not have any cookies, and the request will happen async. Therefore, no matter what you do, the request does not have any cookies. You cannot lock requests (as you would have to). Therefore, that's unfortunately not possible :-(

Comment: Sure? The requests do have cookies (just double-checked, HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies works fine).

Comment: Looks like you are almost there. You can use IRequiresSessionState in your handler and track user activities as well. Examples are click through rate of links, users session time, time user spent on a page etc.

Comment: Prashant, happy to hear that I'm almost there but I have no clues how to use IRequiresSessionState :( Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Using an IP address is a potentially dangerous situation.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use iframes, Use Master Pages. Create a Master Page, and put this code on the top of your "mypage.aspx"

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" ...
```